# How create DataSource for my class like UITableDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, datasource

I have a class GraphView(xib + class). Chart view with labels and other UI elements.
I need to create DataSource protocol for this class it was realized in UITableView, as UITableDataSource.
That needs for more comfortable working with data, which I want load to my GraphView.

If you know how do this or have link to this question solution, please help me. 
Thanks for all questions!

Comment: Protocol will help you in that : https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/all-about-protocols-in-swift-11a72d6ea354 , https://www.raywenderlich.com/814-introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a custom DataSource works just like a Delegate pattern.

```
protocol GraphViewDataSource: class {
  func numberOfRow(for graph: GraphView) -> Int
}

class GraphView {
  weak var dataSource: GraphViewDataSource?

  init() {
    let numberOfRow = dataSource?.numberOfRow(for: self)
  }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to set your `dataSource` property to `weak` to avoid reference cycle (this is why `GraphViewDataSource` need to be constrained to `class`).

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like

```
protocol GraphDataSource {

    func Graph(_ graph:GraphView , row:Int)->UIView
}

protocol GraphDelegate {

    func Graph(_ graph:GraphView ,didSelect row:Int)
}

class GraphView:UIView {

    weak open var dataSource:GraphDataSource?

    weak open var delegate:GraphDelegate?

    func configureHere() {

        let v = dataSource?.Graph(self, row: 0)
        delegate?.Graph(self, didSelect: 0)
    }

}
class ViewController: UIViewController , GraphDataSource , GraphDelegate {


   let g = GraphView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        g.delegate = self
        g.dataSource = self

    }


    func Graph(_ graph: GraphView, didSelect row: Int) {

    }

    func Graph(_ graph: GraphView, row: Int) -> UIView {

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `datasource`and delegate should be weak!

Comment: @AnderCover sure , I'm highlighting main structure

Comment: Yep but this might be copy/pasted as is ;)